# Why in this context can a non-type template parameter not be auto?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, auto, c++17

The simplest snippet I managed to get to reproduce the problem is as follows:

```
#include <variant>

template <auto V>
using ic = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>;

enum { shake }; 
int milk(ic<shake>);

template <class...>
struct context {
    template <auto V>
    decltype(milk(ic<V>{})) get() {
        return std::get<decltype(milk(ic<V>{}))>(value);
    }
    std::variant<int> value;
};

int main(){
    context<int> c;
    c.get<shake>();
}
```

There is something fishy going on here in [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R07W3SF4Lt32QLHF) as it suggests that:

```
prog.cc:13:42: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'auto'
        return std::get<decltype(milk(ic<V>{}))>(value);
                                         ^
prog.cc:3:16: note: template parameter is declared here
template <auto V>
               ^
1 error generated.
```

When we change the `ic` to an aliased type or use the untemplated version of `context` everything works as expected. So is it really clang's bug or am I missing something obvious here?

PS. In [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pUB49IULWP9HDnUO) everything works as expected...

Comment: As a complete aside, `std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(V)>, V>;` works a bit better in a few contexts in my experience; maybe due to early defects in `auto` implementations however, as `auto` should already be suitable for storage.  I'm unsure.

Comment: There are a few clang bugs where making a class a template makes the code fail to compile. It's highly likely that this is another one of them.

Comment: Also an aside, why not use `std::invoke_result_t` instead of `decltype(milk(ic<V>{}))`?

Comment: Yes, it is a [Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35655).

Comment: @xskxzr certainly looks like this bug report might cover the issue, thanks...

Comment: Same as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48106476/2069064

Answer (score 2):

[Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35655) as commented by xskxzr